# Clean/Short URLs using .htaccess is not working as it should

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've been following some YouTube videos to try and get this working but it doesn't seem to want to. This is how my .htaccess file is looking:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$l
```

**I am completely new to .htaccess**, I'm not completely sure how it works but my common sense tells me to just create a file, call it .htaccess and place it in the same folder as my index.php, right?

So when I go to, say index.php/foo/bar or even just /foo/bar/ I get a 404 error.

What are the possible problems? It's a Windows 2008 Server with PHP 5.3.10 installed.

Comment: .htaccess usually goes in the root of the website.

Comment: Will it cease to work if it is not in the root?

Comment: You have also doubled up on "RewriteRule" on your last line. Only need it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As beginning your last line should be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$l
```

And it should work as you expect it... pass all requests but ones for existing files/folders into `index.php`

The `.htaccess` can be in any folder which is hit by the request `URL`... the only difference is the base of the `URL` which is relative to the folder where is the `.htaccess` located

Example:

```
/folder1
 .htaccess
 index.php
 /folder2
 .htaccess
 index.php
```

If you access `/test.php` none if your `.htaccess` files will be processed (it's not related to the request `URI`.

If you access `/folder1/test.php` the corresponding `.htaccess` in `folder1` will be used and the `$1` in your `RewriteRule` will show `test.php`, the `/folder1/` will be stripped from the `URI`.

If you access `/folder1/folder2/test.php` it's similar... apache will use `.htaccess` from `folder2`... the one from `folder1` will be ignored (a bit counderintuitive)

Comment: It didn't solve this problem but would have caused another problem so thanks.

Comment: @F4r-20 what problem... pls update your question, will try to help

Comment: I'm still getting a 404 error, but as a technician myself I know that this can be a hard problem to solve due to the many factors that you can't see. I am currently working on a solution I will let you know how it goes.